# How to update value in inserted row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, cte

I have a table `t1`

```
create table t1 (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(64),
  str2 varchar(64)
);
```

I want to get the row ID and update a field `str2` in this row.

I tried this:

```
WITH inserted AS (
  insert into t1(id, name) values (38, 'www') returning *
) UPDATE t1 SET str2='aaa' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted);
select * from t1;
```

I expected:

```
| id | name |   str2 |
|----|------|--------|
| 38 |  www |   aaa  |
```

But the actual result was:

```
| id | name |   str2 |
|----|------|--------|
| 38 |  www | (null) |
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/410f5/2) for a reproduction scenario.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you also trying to retrieve the newly inserted `id` after the insert? You can achieve this with `returning id`

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in using UPDATE to rows INSERTed in the same statement, as the INSERT could set the missing column in the first place:

```
insert into t1(id, name, str2) values (38, 'www', 'aaa');
```

Besides the pointlessness, it doesn't work, as shown in the question.

The reason is mentioned in the doc in [7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter
> 13), so they cannot "see" one another's effects on the target tables
>
> [...]
>
> Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not
> supported. Only one of the modifications takes place, but it is not
> easy (and sometimes not possible) to reliably predict which one. This
> also applies to deleting a row that was already updated in the same
> statement: only the update is performed. Therefore you should
> generally avoid trying to modify a single row twice in a single
> statement. In particular avoid writing WITH sub-statements that could
> affect the same rows changed by the main statement or a sibling
> sub-statement. The effects of such a statement will not be
> predictable.

Comment: I can't modify the insert, I can only use it as a subquery of  my query

Comment: @user5955758 you say you can't modify the insert but seems like you could modify the whole statement to have more ctes? Seems weird to me.